# Unicode - String - list Manipulation

Tags: python, string, unicode, operation

I have a data `s = u"[u'38', u'36', u'34', u'32']"` which has data type unicode
i want to make this data as simple list of element like `s= ['38','36','32']`,
i try to use simplejson.loads but its not working simple json work with the ('["s"]') this type of string not ("['s']") so any buddy please guide me to get of this problem

thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
>>> import ast
>>> s = u"[u'38', u'36', u'34', u'32']"
>>> [ item.encode('ascii') for item in ast.literal_eval(s) ]
['38', '36', '34', '32']
```

Answer (score 1):

If [`ast`](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html) is available, you can use [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

Answer (score 1):

Well the problem is that that string is not valid JSON syntax. It is valid *Python* syntax, but not JSON, for two reasons:

1. JSON doesn't allow single-quote strings, `'38'`, only double-quote, `"38"`.
2. JSON doesn't allow a u before the string, `u"38"`, only bare strings which are implicitly Unicode, `"38"`.

You need to either change the input format, or use something which can process Python strings instead.

You could use `eval`, which reads strings containing Python syntax, but note that this is highly dangerous if you are accepting arbitrary input, since someone can supply code to execute. Nevertheless, it works:

```
>>> eval(u"[u'38', u'36', u'34', u'32']")
[u'38', u'36', u'34', u'32']
```

**Edit**: khachik's answer is probably better than `eval`, since it won't be susceptible to evaluating arbitrary Python code, only reading Python data structures.

Answer (score 0):

Use `re` module to split your string into needed elements. For example

```
re.findall("u\'([^\']+)\'", u"[u'38', u'36', u'34', u'32']")
```